# ASP.NET MVC4 bundles do not exist in release build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My ASP.NET MVC4 project works fine in debug builds, as long as I don't mind repeatedly rebuilding and republishing when it gets a little confused and "loses" the bundles, as it often does.

> *It appears the "losing" of bundles is related somehow to one of my layouts, 
>   which inserts the content of the CSS bundles directly into the page, to 
>   generate templates for our doc management to display "documents" which 
>   consist of form fields. If I build and then the first thing I do is load the
>   page with that layout first, MVC4 decides the bundles don't exist,
>   until I do a clean build, and reload the page with a different layout.*
>
> *So I'm doing something out of the ordinary there.*

Now I've tried a release build, and the try-again method doesn't work with that. MVC generates the following tags in the page. These resources do not exist on the server. There is no `bundles` directory. The `Content` and `Content/themes/base` directories exist, but nothing in them is called `css`, and I get a 404 when I try to load any of the linked resources. The page has no CSS and no script.

This code in my layout file...

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

...becomes...

```
<link href="/MyApp/Content/css?v=BoqupuQxZQpXG1tSIMNZQqNVpJ_E-NUxg_QIsyvmKn01" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/MyApp/Content/themes/base/css?v=myqT7npwmF2ABsuSaHqt8SCvK8UFWpRv7T4M8r3kiK01" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/MyApp/bundles/modernizr?v=qVODBytEBVVePTNtSFXgRX0NCEjh9U_Oj8ePaSiRcGg1"></script>
<script src="/MyApp/bundles/jquery?v=JzhfglzUfmVF2qo-weTo-kvXJ9AJvIRBLmu11PgpbVY1"></script>
<script src="/MyApp/bundles/jqueryui?v=EHft7nwilnDMnejvwTyEKn_C5lwIsN1M3Xyb8c9OmSQ1"></script>
```

How do you make this work? Is it a configuration thing? I found one guy here [whose solution is to say that "it should work"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12079396/424129), and I agree. However, in my case it actually turns out *not* to work, so that solution may not be the right one for my particular situation here.

I've noticed a fair number of things in MVC4 are simply broken, and the bundling feature is undeniably buggy; is the Release configuration just not functional at all?

I've tried the suggestion to turn off debug in `web.config`,

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

...but that has no effect. Anyway I can't find a way to force `Web.Release.config` to insert that into the output `web.config`.

UPDATE

If I put

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

...at the bottom of `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles`, it does the bundling thing correctly in the VS dev server when I "run" by hitting F5. If I change that to `false` and hit F5, it renders a set of script and whatnot tags referencing the individual files in the bundles. Both work correctly -- on my dev machine. So let's set it to `false` and publish...

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

That works when I publish to the server, even if it's a Release build.

So, there's a workaround.

Comment: It almost sounds like your source js and css files are not deployed to the server. The /bundles directory is a virtual directory, it does not exist. Post your actual BundleConfig.cs, and make sure those source files exist on the server.

Comment: @danludwig BundleConfig.cs is exactly what the wizard created. The files included by BundleConfig.cs all exist on the server. Is there any IIS7 configuration necessary for the `bundles` virtual directory?

Comment: No, no need to configure IIS for that, it's MVC job

Answer (score 1):

Somehing is broken with your mvc4 or VS installation, because it should works. Besides that, `MyApp/Content/css` must be a file in the folder Content of your project. If it is not, then you should configure in `bundlers`each file that will be served for each bundler, but when you created your MVC project the project template had to included this for you.

Comment: Yes, MVC4 is broken. What kind of file would `MyApp\Content\css` be?

Comment: Because you are referencing this as an style with `@Styles.Render` then it should be an stylesheet file, a .css file. Those files that you are referencing with `@Scripts.Render` must be javascripts files.