# CSS files are not showing on server - ASP.NET MVC Bundles error. 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, publish

My MVC 4 application works fine on my local computer.

However, the CSS files are not working after I publish (are not affecting the layout of the website).

I can see CSS the files are on the server.

When I look at the source code, I can see

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=fxCdHAOgPDvcROxkMfEwGQggO9uCfzckN3PaN8BOIzI1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

where as on my local computer, the source code shows as

```
<link href="/Content/css/myFile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/myFile02.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

So, in the source code view on the server, I clicked on  `Content/css?v=fxCdHAOgPDvcROxkMfEwGQggO9uCfzckN3PaN8BOIzI1` and the browser took me to a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I am adding the CSS files with the BunldeConfig.cs class

```
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/javascript").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/1.9.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jTools.js",
                        "~/Scripts/script.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/Css/website.css", 
                "~/Content/Css/banner.css", 
                "~/Content/Css/reusable.css",
                "~/Content/Css/lists.css",
                "~/Content/Css/tooltip.css",
                "~/Content/Css/overlay.css"
                ));


        }
    }
```

My question is, assuming this isn't an IT issue with the server (it has been working fine until recently) is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `~/Content/css` as a bundle alias in `new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")`, **while this path actually exists**.

So when you are requesting `<link href="/Content/css?...>` you are essentially asking for a directory listing and that is forbidden.

Try using something else, like `new StyleBundle("~/Content/styles")`.

**NOTE**: If you do use something like `~/Content/styles` as an alias you may have issues with relative urls in your `.css` files. It may seem odd, but you may better use something like `~/Content/Css/someAlias`

Comment: Sigh - I actually knew this, about 2 years ago ... It's odd what you forget when you stop using things. Thank you, resolved perfectly

Comment: You are welcome. A small suggestion for future reference. It would be more helpfull to others if you changed your title to something like `ASP.NET MVC Bundles error. 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.`

Comment: I was having the same issue. I rename bundle as 
<styleBundle path="~/Content/styles">
and my master page as
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/styles" />
and everything is good

Comment: Renaming from~/Content/css to ~/Content/someothername worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the section of `<system.web>`of your root web.config file , the debug mode is not included. when you publish your application it does not include the debug attribute. So you include the following code:

`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">` instead of `<compilation  targetFramework="4.5">` in your web.config file.

For more info You can follow the [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app/12079396#12079396) .

Comment: This solve the symptom but does not fix the cause. For the correct answer refer to @lalibi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have any physical folder `css` inside `Content` folder this problem occurs.. To resolve it either you remove the physical `css` folder or rename it to `any-other` name .