# How to Link FontAwesome.css via MVC4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, font-awesome

I have MVC4 web app project and I want to use http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

I have font awesome folder inside Content directory and I have in my Layout file this

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or this

```
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in debug it works but after uploading on iis server it does not work (edit: I mean it does not show the images), how can I implement that .css? I'm using Razor.

EDIT: I discover some weird behaviour. In debug mode with VS the IE load CSS fine.

After deploying on IIS the IE cannot load CSS. But **Chrome does load CSS** !
I check it on several PCs and delete history and cache, so now application users are using Chrome in access to that App :-P

Comment: You need to elaborate on "after uploading on iis server it does not work". How does it not work? Does it throw an error, or render the wrong content, or no content at all?

Comment: it dont display the fonts, no errors.

Comment: Does it render a <link> element in the markup? what is the href attribute that gets rendered on the server?

Comment: It render 
<link href="/VirtualDirectoryName/Content/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Other .css file work.

Comment: When you navigate to that file on the server, does it exist? If so, where in the markup are you applying fontawesome css styles?

Comment: This post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app

Comment: danludwig: yes on the server the .css file does exist. About bundling.. this is mandatory (must have) function which i need to configure to load this type of .css ?! Its more complicated then my application itself :D

Answer (score 1):

AppStart-> BundleConfig 
inside `RegisterBundle()` function add a new bundle

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/AwFontcss").Include("~/Content/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"));
```

then in your view just include this bundle.

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/AwFontcss")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you but if i dont have BundleConfig in AppStart directory, should i create it manually ?

Comment: How are the basic css loading then? you can create your own.. you have to register it in global.ascx

Comment: I have only one simple Default.css which is loaded with <link> attribute, i have no experience with bundling and im reading about it right know, its seems to me like elephant for my purpose but i dont know other way :P

Answer (score 0):

Your most certain problem is that your Font files is not deployed to the server.
By default, the VS deploy doesn't include those files.

You can check the contents of your Content folder in the server... and if a file is missing... just manually copy it,
.

Comment: Thank you for a tip, but i see it in the project and after deploy the files are on the server.

Comment: Type the url for that file in browser and check if it is being rendered. there might be an issue with permissions.

Comment: URL is okay but im affraid of this in that .css
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0')
this dont work

Comment: Use CDN for that font

Comment: In Chrome it works and in IE in debug mode too, only in IE on production it dont :P