# website text only when run it from iis manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

this is my first time using IIS Manager to deploy Website, I built my website using MVC 4 Visual Studio. When i run from Visual Studio this is the
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rP6s.jpg)

but when i deploy using IIS Manager. this is the 
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnNWg.jpg)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solve, I open IIS Manager and Open Directory Browsing, at the right side, click enable.

Answer (score 0):

CSS are not loading Please verify the path of CSS and js files. For more information please use inspect element in your browser .

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I dont know where I can verify the path.

Comment: If you are using chrome than just press F12 and then go to sources tab.or follow this link   https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles

Comment: http://localhost/Content/site.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
The path is verified.

Comment: Yes ,It means browser is unable to fetch CSS and js files from the specified path...check the path on clicking the error.

Comment: Use @Url.Content("~/path/file.htm") for your js and css files

Comment: you have to put this code where you are linking your js and css file.Maybe to your master page(_Layout.cshtml) in your shared folder.

Comment: it doesn't work :( there is @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") in my _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Just for check.Please  Replace @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")  with       <link href=@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") rel="stylesheet" /> and check is it working.

Comment: not working sir , if Visual Studio,its working well, but not in the IIS Manager
but no error in Inspect Element

Comment: Please refer this link.Might it help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app