# ASPNET MVC 5 production/live site not checking "Content" folder for fonts, thus giving me a 404 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, production-environment

So the path to my icon font is this:

```
SITE > Content > Ionicons > Fonts > ionicons.woff
```

However, when I publish to the production site, the site is looking in:

```
SITE > Ionicons > Fonts > ionicons.woff
```

skipping the Content folder.

But when I manually move the font folder in to the root site folder, it works. How can I make it so the site checks the Content folder instead?

Comment: You should be able to address this within the Route Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an old thread: [Why is my CSS bundling not working with a bin deployed MVC4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app)

All I had to do was add this to my webServer section in my web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```