# How to acess AreasController that is in controller folder that is outside of .Net's Areas Folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a Controller called AreasController, I added Areas folder to the project so I can create some Areas, by doing this I noticed that the url: /Areas is pointing to Areas folder not to my AreasController.

Is there a way to solve this, or I'll have to rename AreasController.

Comment: Hi Raphael, I hope answer to your question is already available here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/22681453/3397630 , Kindly let me know whether that solved your problem thanks karthik

Comment: This didn't work =/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the associated route to that controller by adding an annotation on the top of the class name

as here:

```
[Route("Areas")]
```

for more reading please check [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)