# How to create menu link in ASP.NET MVC with Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I save menu links in my database with the format: "master/country", master is area name, and country is controller name. My web URL is http://localhost/appname. When I click the country menu, its redirects to the country page (http://localhost/appname/master/country). But when I click again the City menu item (in master area too), it redirects to http://localhost/appname/**master/master**/city. I write menu links in a `StringBuilder` (including a  tag) and store it in `viewbag`.

I tried changing menu links to "/master/country", then the URL becomes http://localhost/master/country when I click first menu (country).

I am using MVC 5. How to create a links menu within the same area?

Answer (score 1):

This will help access an `area` from an action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("MyText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "YourAreaName"}, null)
```

This will [help you more options on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2709915/6085193)

Or you create an area specified with controllers using above link

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" }, new{})
```

Comment: I create method at different Project. I think Html.ActionLink and Html.ActionLink must be in System.Web.Mvc.Controller class. How to call HtmlActionLink in different project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in action method

```
 return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" });
```